# How to set buttons with text above using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to set buttons in one line and text3 was in line between text1 and text2. After descrase a size of the window, i want text1, text 2 buttoon, seperate text 3 and button.

I will very gratefully for any help.

my code:
    
        
         
                Hello

```
      <div class="row center">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <strong>text1</strong>
            <p><strong>text2</strong></p>
            <button>download</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <p><strong>text3</strong></p>
            <button>download</button>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

and css:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0;
}

.orange {
    color: #FF6600;
}

button {
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border:0;
    background-color: #FF6600;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[Link to demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fq3arw95/)

Comment: Your questions is a little confusing. Can you post an image of how you want the layout to look before and after re-sizing window?

Comment: Clear in your question what you need exactly